# Steenrod squares in terms of chain maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sq{Sq}$The Steenrod squares $\Sq^i: H^n({-};\mathbb{F}_2) \to
H^{n+i}({-};\mathbb{F}_2)$ are fundamental cohomological
operations. By the Yoneda lemma, they induce a map between the
Eilenberg–MacLane spaces $K(\mathbb{F}_2; n) \to
K(\mathbb{F}_2; n +i)$. By the Dold–Kan correspondence, this map
should be expressible as a chain map (if I'm not mistaken): $$\widehat{\Sq^i}: \mathbb{F}_2[-n]
\to \mathbb{F}_2[-(n+i)].$$

---

**Question**: How do we explicitly describe $\widehat{\Sq^i}$? Is it much harder to do this for other finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Answer (score 9):

You do have a map of spaces $Sq^i : K(\mathbb F_2 , n) \to K(\mathbb F_2, n+i)$, but it is not a map of topological abelian groups unless $i=0$ or $i=1$. The Dold-Kan correspondence says that maps of chain complexes correspond to maps of topological abelian groups. So there is no map of chain complexes realizing $Sq^i$ for $i\neq 0, 1$.

For $i=0$, there is -- it's the identity map. For $i=1$, $Sq^1$ is the Bockstein, and is again represented by a map of chain complexes, but it's not $\mathbb F_2$-linear, only $\mathbb Z$-linear.

In fact, if $A$ is a free resolution of $\mathbb F_2$ as a chain complex, you can see that there are no $\mathbb Z$-linear maps $A \to A$ of degree $>1$ because $\mathbb Z$ has homological dimension 1. You can see that there are no $\mathbb F_2$-linear maps of degree $>0$ because $\mathbb F_2$ has homological dimension $0$.

On the spectrum side, these observations correspond to the fact that $Sq^i : H \mathbb F_2 \to H\mathbb F_2 [i]$ is not an $H\mathbb F_2$-linear map for $i > 0$, and not $H\mathbb Z$-linear for $i > 1$.

Comment: Steenrod operation could be defined for "homology" classes of $E_2$-$\mathbb F_2$-algebras (or even for complexes $V\in D(\mathbb F_2$ equipped with a symmetric multiplication $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)\to V$ (as in [Lurie's notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~lurie/917notes/Lecture2.pdf)). It looks like the whole thing lives in $D(\mathbb F_2)$ and it seems strange at first glance of nonlinearity.

Comment: @Z.M Actually given that the Steenrod squares are quadratic maps, lack of linearity is *very* unsurprising. The fact that they are $\mathbb{S}$-linear is surprising, but this comes from the fact that they are an avatar of the Frobenius (another quadratic map which turns out to be linear)

Comment: I asked this question because in Lurie's note the construction doesn't seem natural to me. Is there a better explanation of why Steenrod operations exist (in that way)? Or rather, what's a good way to understand the space $[K(\mathbb{F}_q; n), K(\mathbb{F}_q; n+i)]$ systematically?

Comment: @Student You can try to look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.00048). It's very conceptual, but it's far from elementary. There is no way of systematically compute cohomology operations, as far as I know, even if the answer is known for ordinary cohomology.